# Number that represents the unique index of many arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an application that takes in multiple arrays of data each or variable length. I plan on cycling through and displaying every combination of data for each array I'm given. My first inclination was to have a single number represent the state of each array since I know the number of combinations is the product of the number of elements of each array.

So for example:

A = [0,1,2,3]

B = [0,1,2,3]

C = [0,1]

So  4 x 4 x 2 = 32 combinations I need to represent

I've managed to represent all states by applying modulo and division to a given index using each array.length. My problem is that it doesn't order well (see snippet below). Has anyone solved a similar problem or know how I could change the algorithm to get it in order?

```js
function multiArrayIndex(index, ...args) {
    var arrays = args.slice();
    var output = [];
    
    for (var i = 0, curIndex = index; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        var curArray = arrays[i];
        var valueIndex =(curIndex % curArray.length);
        output.push(curArray[valueIndex]);
        curIndex = Math.ceil(curIndex / curArray.length);
    }
    return output;
}
demoP = document.getElementById("demo");
for(var i = 32; i>=1; i--){
 demoP.innerHTML = demoP.innerHTML + i + " - " + multiArrayIndex(i, [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [0,1] ) + "<br />";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What does "ordering well" mean? What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: An index that if incremented, would increment/decrement one of the underlying arrays in a predictable manner. So maybe if my snippet produced  
32-0,0,0
31-1,0,0
30-2,0,0
29-3,0,0
28-0,1,0
27-1,1,0
26-2,1,0
25-1,1,0
24-2,1,0
23-3,1,0
22-0,2,0
Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the indices separate would be a nicer approach in my opinion.

Incrementing the indices could work kinda similar to how we added two numbers by hand in elementary school - if an index is too large, set it to zero and increment the next one by one:

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
var b = [0, 1, 2, 3]
var c = [0, 1]

var state = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}

function increment() {
  state.a++;

  if (state.a >= a.length) {
    state.b++;
    state.a = 0;
  }
  if (state.b >= b.length) {
    state.c++;
    state.b = 0;
  }
  if (state.c >= c.length) {
    state.c = 0;
  }

  console.log(state);
}

console.log(state);
```

```html
<button onclick='increment()'>Increment</button>
```

Updating the document based on the `state` should be trivial from here.

Comment: Thanks, that'll probably work for my my usecase. Although, part of me still wants the power of being able to jump between different states :P

Comment: You can always serialize the state, store it and replace it later!

Comment: You're right, and I'm more or less doing that, but with an increment/decrement function I can only manipulate the state relative to the state I'm in. I can increment n times to change the state from the current state to state + n. I'd like to access state[n].